# What's the fastest thing to farm?

Tags: growtopia

I've always wanted to know the answer so I can get World Locks quick.

What's the fastest thing to farm in Growtopia?

It's generally used by calculating how many seeds you need, how much time it takes, etc. So I need to know.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to profit World Locks fast, then the question shouldn't be what's the *fastest* farmable, but what's the farmable with the best *price/rarity/farmability/punches-to-break* ratio.
The *fastest* known farmables are Grass, Rock Background and a bunch of other cheap stuff.
The farmable with the best *price/rarity/farmability/punches-to-break* ratio, which means it's just worth farming, is nowadays Fishtank - Cost 100-120/WL, rarity 42, great farmability and 3 punches to break. That just sounds awesome, doesn't it?
Other farmables that are worth farming (not as much as Fishtanks though): Venus Guytrap (200/WL, 41, slightly-above-average, 6), Blackrock Wall (200/WL, 42, slightly-above-average, 4) and Pinball Bumper, which doesn't have such good specs at all.
I personally definitely recommend using the Fishtanks.

Comment: There's also the option of chandeliers which would drop more gems, but they are slower to break and cost a fair bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get world locks fast I recommend you to farm laser grids for a farmable.

But farming farmable isn’t exactly the best way to get rich.

Watching profit videos on YouTube and doing project helps you earn a lot of world locks.
In fact if you play 2 hours a day for a month you can earn about 5-10 diamond locks!

Answer (score 0):

I also would recommend laser grids. Fish tanks as Prokop Hanzl said, yes as they drop a few gems, easy to break and are fast at growing. However, laser grids are also easy to break, and fish tanks they don’t drop many gems. How about Chandeliers? Yes, they give a TON of gems, but costs a lot, and take FOREVER to grow. Laser grids are in the middle. It’s easy to break, they still give a ton of gems; Only a few less than chands, and they take half the time to grow compared to chands. They’re also not super expensive.